# GPO not applied (unknown reason)

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, domain

I have a **user configuration** GPO (nothing on the computer side and computer configuration is disabled), linked to a **user only OU**.

I need to filter the users on which the GPO apply. When using specific users or groups in the security filtering, the GPO is not applied on the user side : "Not applied (unknown reason)."
When using the default "Authenticated users" group the GPO is applied.

I'm on a W 2012 R2 domain with W10 clients.

I'm lost. Any ideas ?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/06/22/deploying-group-policy-security-update-ms16-072-kb3163622

Comment: @joeqwerty, could you wrap this up with an answer so this can get accepted and solved?  Edit: Actually nevermind, it's a duplicate